# configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `＝'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is the error that I get when running 'rails c production' error

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method`＝' for # (NoMethodError)
      from /Users/kgb/idyll/config/environments/production.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in`class_eval'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
      from /Users/kgb/idyll/config/environments/production.rb:1:in`'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`block in require'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in`each'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`each'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in`each'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in`tsort_each'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in`initialize!'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
      from /Users/kgb/idyll/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in`require_environment!'
      from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
      from bin/rails:4:in`require'
      from bin/rails:4:in `'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry,first time post error.I already fix my error.
run rails c production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you're using the Unicode character U+FF1D (FULLWIDTH EQUALS SIGN) instead of a regular equals sign (U+003D). From the stack trace, I say that you need to check the "equals" sign you have in `/Users/feel989/idyll/config/environments/production.rb` line 32.